# Puzzle game - converting binary numbers to decimal

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-3.x, quiz

I've been learning Python for a few weeks and I created a simple game where you convert binary numbers to decimal. It shows you *n* binary numbers and you are supposed to enter the numbers in decimal system in sequence as a password. After failing three times you lose. I'd like to implement it into a bigger game later.

Here's the code:

```
import random


# Conver decimal to binary.
def toBin(i):
    bin = "{0:b}".format(i)
    return bin


# Generate random password and it's binary version.
def generatePassword(n):
    password = []
    passwordBin = []
    for i in range(n):
        a = random.randint(0, 9)
        password.append(a)
        passwordBin.append(toBin(a))
    return password, passwordBin


# Prints the binary password and a frame.
def printPassword(password):
    print(12 * '#')
    for i in range(len(password[1]) + 4):
        if i <= 1:
            print(2 * '#' + 8 * ' ' + 2 * '#')
        elif i <= 5:
            print(2 * '#' + password[1][i - 2].rjust(4, '0').center(8) + 2 * '#')
        else:
            print(2 * '#' + 8 * ' ' + 2 * '#')
    print(12 * '#')


# The game loop.
def puzzle(n):
    password = generatePassword(n)
    win = False
    endLoop = False
    attempts = 3
    while endLoop is False:
        # Check remaining attempts.
        if attempts > 0:
            printPassword(password)
            print('Attempts remaining: ' + str(attempts) + '\n')
            # Looping through password numbers.
            for i in range(n):
                print('Number ' + str(i + 1), '\t\t', end='')
                # Input and check for ValueError.
                try:
                    inp = int(input())
                except ValueError:
                    print('You can only enter numbers.')
                    break
                # Is input correct?
                if inp == password[0][i]:
                    print('CORRECT')
                else:
                    attempts -= 1
                    print('WRONG\n')
                    break
            # End loop and win.
            else:
                endLoop = True
                win = True
        # End loop.
        else:
            endLoop = True
    # Check win condition.
    if win is True:
        print('ACCESS GRANTED')
    else:
        print('ACCESS DENIED')


# Run the game.
puzzle(4)
```

Are there any ways to improve my code, expecially the puzzle(n) function? The conditions and loops took me some time to get working and still kinda confuse me. I hope there aren't any bugs.

Answer (score 5):

#### Style

Please follow PEP8 conventions on naming: function names should be `lowercase_with_underscores`

On documentation: information on functions should be put below their definition in the form of a docstring, in order to allow programmatic access via `help(function)`.

### `generatePassword`

#### List comprehension

The explicit loop in `generate_password` is unnecessary, it is too long making the reader forget about the logic behind such function.

```
def generate_password_and_binary(n):
    """ A "password" is a list of length `n` containing random digits. """ 
    password = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(n)]
    return password, [to_bin(digit) for digit in password]
```

This version with list comprehension is shorter and more to the point.

I also incorporated the comment into the function name (self-documenting code is better than code + comments) and added a more detailed docstring.

### `printPassword`

I think your `printPassword` has a serious bug:

```
>>> generatePassword(8)
([2, 1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 7, 3], ['10', '1', '111', '110', '100', '101', '111', '11'])
>>> printPassword(_)
############
##        ##
##        ##
##  0010  ##
##  0001  ##
##  0111  ##
##  0110  ##
##        ##
##        ##
##        ##
##        ##
##        ##
##        ##
############
```

Only the first four digits where printed and the rest ignored.
This bug is probably a result of over-complication caused by indexes and comparison, while a plain `for` iteration over the collection is sufficient, here is a simpler (and correct!) way to write this function:

```
def print_password(binary_version): # No need to pass all password if only binary part is shown
    wall = "#" * 12
    spaced = "{0}{1}{0}".format("##", " " * 8)
    print(wall, spaced, sep="\n")
    for binary_digit in binary_version:
        print("{0}{1}{2}{1}{0}".format("##", "  ", binary_digit.rjust(4, "0")))
    print(spaced, wall, sep="\n")
```

Now all of the password is printed:

```
>>> print_password(['10', '1', '111', '110', '100', '101', '111', '11'])
############
##        ##
##  0010  ##
##  0001  ##
##  0111  ##
##  0110  ##
##  0100  ##
##  0101  ##
##  0111  ##
##  0011  ##
##        ##
############
```

Comment: I have started thinking about how to simplify the last of your functions: look here: http://pastie.org/10955242

Comment: Thanks for answer, I found that bug when I was messing around with it later in train. I solved it differently, but your solution seems nicer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `passwordBin` as it is only the representation of an information you already have. And, as such, you don't need `toBin` either. You only need `generatePassword` to return a list of random digits:

```
def generate_password(n):
    return [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(n)]
```

and then, `format` these numbers into `printPassword`:

```
def print_password(digits):
    print('#'*12)
    print('##        ##')
    for digit in digits:
        print('##  {:04b}  ##'.format(digit))
    print('##        ##')
    print('#'*12)
```

---

You can also reduce the complexity of your main loop by:

1. Using a decreasing range: `for remaining in range(3, 0, -1):`
2. Extracting out the "printing" part and having this function only return if the player wins or fails.

Something along the lines of

```
# The game loop.
def puzzle(n):
    password = generate_password(n)
    for attempts in range(3, 0, -1):
        print_password(password)
        print('Attempts remaining:', attempts, '\n')
        win = True
        # Looping through password numbers.
        for i, digit in enumerate(password, 1):
            guess = input('Number {}\t\t'.format(i))
            try:
                guess = int(guess)
            except ValueError:
                print('You can only enter numbers.')
                win = False
                break
            if guess != digit:
                print('WRONG!')
                win = False
                break
            print('CORRECT')
        if win:
            # Every guess were the same as the digits
            return True
    # Attempts exhausted without winning
    return False
```

You may note the use of the prompt parameter of `input` that avoid a call to `print` right before; and the use of `enumerate` that allow to access both the digit and its index at once. The parameter 1 is there to indicate that the indexing start at 1.

Now you could write a `game` function allong the lines of

```
def game(n):
    if puzzle(n):
        print('ACCESS GRANTED')
    else:
        print('ACCESS DENIED')
```

or put this kind of logic under an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) clause.

---

The use of the `win` flag can also be simplified further by using the [`for ... else`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct:

```
def puzzle(n):
    password = generate_password(n)
    for attempts in range(3, 0, -1):
        print_password(password)
        print('Attempts remaining:', attempts, '\n')
        for i, digit in enumerate(password, 1):
            guess = input('Number {}\t\t'.format(i))
            try:
                guess = int(guess)
            except ValueError:
                print('You can only enter numbers.')
                break
            if guess != digit:
                print('WRONG!')
                break
            print('CORRECT')
        else:
            # Every guess were the same as the digits
            return True
    # Attempts exhausted without winning
    return False
```

It can also be simpler (no need to catch an exception) to turn the digits into strings instead of trying to turn the guesses into integers. In the end, I would write something along the lines of:

```
import random


def generate_password(n):
    """Generate a list of n random digits"""
    return [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(n)]


def print_password(digits):
    """Print a list of digits by obfucating their decimal
    representation into binary one.
    """
    print('############')
    print('##        ##')
    for digit in digits:
        print('##  {:04b}  ##'.format(digit))
    print('##        ##')
    print('############')


def puzzle(n, max_attempts=3):
    """Ask the user to guess a list of n random digits
    by providing them with their binary representation.

    Return whether they win or not.
    """
    password = generate_password(n)
    for attempts in range(max_attempts, 0, -1):
        print_password(password)
        print('Attempts remaining:', attempts, '\n')
        for i, digit in enumerate(password, 1):
            guess = input('Number {}\t\t'.format(i))
            if guess != str(digit):
                print('WRONG!')
                break
            print('CORRECT')
        else:
            # Every guess were the same as the digits
            return True
    # Attempts exhausted without winning
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_won = puzzle(10)
    if user_won:
        print('ACCESS GRANTED')
    else:
        print('ACCESS DENIED')
```